# Adding predefined item to a ComboBox with ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I'm trying to add a predefined ComboBoxItem into my ComboBox which already has a ItemsSource property set. example:

```
(Select item)
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
```

It's possible to do this without modifying the original items collection?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is some sample code from MSDN that shows the usage of CompositeCollection:

```
<ComboBox>
    <ComboBox.ItemsSource>
        <CompositeCollection>
            <ListBoxItem>Please Select</ListBoxItem>
            <CollectionContainer Collection="{Binding Source={StaticResource YOURDATASOURCE}}" />
        </CompositeCollection>
    </ComboBox.ItemsSource>
</ComboBox>
```

Here are some references to show you the usage of CompositeCollection:

1- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.compositecollection.aspx

2- http://robertbouillon.com/2010/04/17/adding-items-to-a-data-bound-wpf-combobox/

3- [How do I convert a ComboBox to use a bound CompositeCollection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750784/how-do-i-convert-a-combobox-to-use-a-bound-compositecollection)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to dynamically change the contents of items source, use ObservableCollection instead, so you will have access to Add() method.

```
private ObservableCollection<string> myStrings;

public MyClass()
{
    myStrings = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    myControl.ItemsSource = myStrings;
}

private void AddNewItem(string item)
{
    myStrings.Add(item);
}
```